# Adding text to text box when event ''MouseHover'' is active

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, mousehover

I'm new at C#.
I want to add '#' to HALLO (in the textBox) each time when you hover your mouse over the button.

This is what i have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Q = "HALLO";
    string hashtag = "#";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tB1.Text = Q;
    }

    private void bT1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tB1.Text += hashtag;

        if (Q.Length > 20)
        {
            tB1.Clear();
        }

        lBkarakters.Text = Convert.ToString(tB1.Text.Length);
    }

    }
    }
```

It does add the '#', but HALLO is gone.

Comment: Now we know what you want & what you have - we need to know what your problem is. Knowing winforms/wpf etc would also be useful as they may have different solutions.

Comment: Add this code in MouseHover event of BUtton

Comment: If I run the program, it doesn't add the # to HALLO. Only one time, like: HALLO#, so if I move my mouse over the button twice it must be like this: HALLO##

Comment: Well you've given us the code, but where are you putting it?

Comment: unrelated to your question but you may want to use tB1.Text.equals(Q) instead of tB1.Text == Q

Comment: The MouseHover event of the Button

Comment: @JaydipJ: only for Winforms - wpf doesn't have an hover event.

Comment: Yes it's WindowsForm!

Comment: either you forgot the `+` in `tB1.Text += hashtag;` or you overwrite `Q` and/or `tB1.Text` at some other place in your code. The posted code of yours in this fashion works like a charm...

Comment: @MongZhu the code does work, but I can only see: ### not HALLO###

Comment: then please post the entire code. Because up to now the posted code works AND HALLO does not disappear...

Comment: @MongZhu updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Q = "HALLO";
    string hashtag = "#";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tB1.Text = Q;
    }

    private void bT1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tB1.Text += hashtag;
    }
}
```

or

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Q = "HALLO";
    string hashtag = "#";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tB1.Text = Q;
    }

    private void bT1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tB1.Text += hashtag;
    }
}
```

Make sure you're event is registered:

[image]

Comment: The first one works, but HELLO is gone, the second one doesn't work. And the event is registered

Comment: They both work :) and HALLO will not be removed. Double check the code  you have.

Comment: Checked, still the same. I've updated my code(see above), but if I remove the if statement it will still be the same @Jim

Comment: @Linda if you are new to c# and winforms ... try to copy exact same in a new fresh project and go from there ...

Answer (score 4):

Initialize your textbox somewhere (I'd recommend on the `Load` event handler):

```
tB1.Text = "HALLO";
```

Register an event handler for the `MouseHover` event on the button:

```
this.yourButton.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.yourButton_MouseHover);

// ...

private void yourButton_MouseHover(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    tB1.Text += "#";
}
```